# Azure Devops: how to squash all commits of a PR as a patch to download for test?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops, pull-request

I am working on `Azure DevOps`.

I have a PR (pull request) is made from branch A to branch B, which contains 100+ commits. Now when I merge it to branch B, the PR build throw errors.

Now, I try to understand why the build will fail. I would like to download all commits in this PR as a .patch file so that I can apply it to local repo (on branch B) and build it and see why build break.

Is there a way on Azure DevOps to download the patch from a PR?

I know in github, we can easily do this by add ".patch" in the PR's URL, like this: https://github.com/AAA/BBB/pull/123456.patch is the change patch from PR: https://github.com/AAA/BBB/pull/123456

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below workaround. How did it go?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid azure devops does not have the feature to download the patch file like what you do in github.

As a workaround, you can first clone the azure repo to your local machine, and then use `git format-patch` command to get the patch file.

For example i have a PR from branch working to master in azure devops repo.

See below example:

```
git clone https://org@dev.azure.com/org/proj/_git/repo
git checkout working
git pull
git format-patch master --stdout > ./workingtomaster.patch
```

First i clone the azure devops repo to local machine,  and checkout working branch, then use `git format-patch` command to output the patch file. All the commits in the PR that are about to merge to master branch will be exported to the path file.

However you can also  [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to Microsoft development team, hope they will consider implementing this feature in the future sprint.